# Váriação na localização dependendo do navegador - Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Recentemente comecei a utilizar o Google Maps API, então sei muito pouco sobre.

Ao entrar no site de meu projeto o navegador pergunta se pode obter a localização do usuário. Só que eu percebi que a localização varia dependendo do navegador.
Utilizando o Google Chrome a localização é bem precisa  porém se acessar com o Firefox ou Edge é totalmente diferente..

Por que ocorre esta variação de localização?

Google Chrome (**@-23.6058457,-46.6586903,18.25z**)

Mozilla Firefox (**@-23.6083054,-46.6559814,18.4z**)

Microsoft Edge (**@-23.5346485,-46.6277816,16.91z**) - Muito distante da minha localização.

Tem algo que eu possa mudar em meu código para corrigir esta imprecisão?

```
var geocoder;
            var map;
            var marker;

            function initialize() {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-18.8800397, -47.05878999999999);
                var options = {
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMaps"), options);

                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    draggable: true,
                    icon: 'images/mapicon.png',
                });

                marker.setPosition(latlng);
            }

            // verifica se o navegador tem suporte a geolocalização
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) { // callback de sucesso
                    // ajusta a posição do marker para a localização do usuário
                    //marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
                    initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    map.setCenter(initialLocation);
                    marker.setPosition(initialLocation);

                },
                function (error) { // callback de erro
                    alert('Erro ao obter localização!');
                    console.log('Erro ao obter localização.', error);
                });
            } else {
                console.log('Navegador não suporta Geolocalização!');
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A precisão é determinada pelo navegador, mas você pode, via código, pedir que o navegador te dê maior precisão. Não há garantia de que ele vá conseguir, mas ele vai tentar.

No seu código, crie o dicionario options:

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};
```

Em seguida o insira como terceiro parâmetro na chamada do getCurrentPosition:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) { // callback de sucesso
                    // ajusta a posição do marker para a localização do usuário
                    //marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
                    initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    map.setCenter(initialLocation);
                    marker.setPosition(initialLocation);

                },
                function (error) { // callback de erro
                    alert('Erro ao obter localização!');
                    console.log('Erro ao obter localização.', error);
                }, options );
```

Note que a função poderá levar mais tempo para retornar.

Um outra opção que pode te ajudar é a função watchPosition, ela te informa quando ocorrem alterações na posição do usuário e isso pode te trazer mais precisão. Alguns celulares, por exemplo, enviam primeiro uma informação com menor precisão e só aumentam a precisão com o decorrer do tempo.

```
id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, options);
```

Os parâmetros a serem passados são basicamente os mesmos da getCurrentPosition, mas lembre-se que essa função chamará suas callbacks toda vez que a posição mudar. Já o valor de retorno ID pode ser utilizado para desativar a watchPosition:

```
navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(id);
```

Outro fator que talvez possa te ajudar é o atributo accuracy do objeto position.coords, que sua função success recebe quando é chamada. Ele te diz qual é a precisão das coordenadas encontradas.

Tudo isso pode te ajudar, mas nada disso vai garantir boa precisão. O Google tem muito mais recursos para saber sua localização mais precisamente que os demais. O Chrome pode, por exemplo, utilizar os dados do streetview(que coleta os dados de todas as redes wifi por onde os carros do google passam) para obter maior precisão.

Mais detalhes sobre o options: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions
Mais sobre o Position.coords: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Coordinates

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition

EDIT: Notei que você já possui um dicionario chamado options em seu código, dê outro nome qualquer ao dicionario que citei a cima.

Comment: Antonio, obrigado pelo retorno. 
Fiz exatamente como orientou mas a localização continua sendo a mesma que mencionei :/

Comment: Então, é como eu disse, ele tenta obter uma precisão maior, mas ele pode não conseguir. O google certamente tem mais recursos para obter melhores localizações que seus concorrentes, o chrome pode, por exemplo, utilizar dados do streetview para ajudar na precisão(os carros do streetview coletam dados das redes wifi por onde passam). Vou editar meu post adicionando um outro método que talvez possa te ajudar, mas você sempre estará restrito as capacidades e recursos de cada browser e, quanto a isso, não há o que fazer.